# BASIC Authentication and SSL configuration failed in Tomcat 6.0

Tags: java, xml, ssl, tomcat6, basic-authentication

The application is a simple JSP/Servlet application.I want to perform a user authentication (using BASIC Authentication) and if the user is authenticated, then I will redirect them to the home screen using SSL (i.e. https). **The BASIC Authentication has to be performed on clicking a button.**

For achieveing this; initially I configured the BASIC Authentication in my web.xml like this:

```
<security-role>
  <role-name>Admin</role-name>      
</security-role>
<security-role>
  <role-name>Guest</role-name>
</security-role>
<security-constraint>      
  <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>BasicDemo</web-resource-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
      <http-method>POST</http-method>
  </web-resource-collection>
  <auth-constraint>
      <role-name>Admin</role-name>
  </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<login-config>
  <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>      
</login-config>
```

The user BASIC Authentcation part of the code works perfectly (the popup dialog appears asking for the username and password and it works fine)

Then I configured SSL by following the following steps:

1) Generated a Keystore using keytool

2) Added the below entry in the server.xml:

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
           maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" 
       keystoreFile="${user.home}/.keystore"
       keystorePass="password" />
```

3) Added this in web.xml inside the

```
<user-data-constraint>
      <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
  </user-data-constraint>
```

On running the application, below are the issues I have with it:

1) On clicking the button (for which the BASIC authentication has to be performed),  the dialog for authentication did not appeared (which appears for BASIC Authentication asking for username and password)

2) I was redirected to a link with https (yes the https appeared in the url) with GET and the doGet() method of the servlet gets executed which is incorrect since the submit button form is like this, henc the doPost method should be executed rather than the doGet:

```
<form action="CentralController" method="post">
```

One mistake from my side may be using the POST rather than GET for authentication but still I feel this should work, I might be missing something and hence it does not work. Please let me know where are the issues and how to resolve it achieve what I am expecting.

**EDIT**

Servlet definition in **web.xml**

```
 <servlet>
  <servlet-name>CentralController</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.controller.CentralController</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>CentralController</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/CentralController</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

This is the form:

```
<form action="CentralController" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: You'll need to look at setting up a Realm if you want the container to perform the basic authentication.

Comment: BTW, as far as I know, `Realm` is "database" of usernames and passwords that identify valid users of a web application which I don't need since I have added the roles along with their username and password in the `tomcat-users.xml`. The Basic Authentication is working fine (without SSL implementation in web.xml) but when I add the SSL configuration in the web.xml, then the Basic Authentication is not working. I am getting the list of issues mentioned above. Why is it behaving like this? Please help

Comment: Ah ok - sorry wasn't clear from the question initially

Comment: can you post your default connector configuration (the unsecure one, usually port 8080) ?

Comment: Do you have an SSL certificate?

Comment: No I dont have one. I have created one usig the above mentioned steps.

Answer (score 3):

On the get/post conversion, if I understand your scenario correctly, you are experiencing a classic HTTP redirection "issue".

When hitting the SSL security constraint with an non-SSL request, the server sends the client a HTTP 302 response, also known as a redirect, to an https URL.
The implementation of this redirect is not exactly the same on all client HTTP stacks, but basically most of the time, the redirection is handled by issuing a GET whatever the original HTTP verb was (POST or other).

You can find many discussions about this on wikipedia and its links
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302
See also [Response.Redirect with POST instead of Get?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46582/response-redirect-with-post-instead-of-get) and [HTTP: POST request receives a 302, should the redirect-request be a GET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8138137/http-post-request-receives-a-302-should-the-redirect-request-be-a-get) for a discussion.
Or generally on google, "HTTP 302 POST".

The sad conclusion is that you can not count on the POST nature of your original request to be preserved when a (HTTP to HTTPS in your case) redirection is sent, it will depend on the browser, and there are many browsers that will issue a GET whatever the redirection status code (302, 307 and the likes).

You might still want to try workarounds as described in the first link above.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Please let me know whether it is a good idea to open a new browser instance whenever I redirect from http to https? Will this resolve the issue since in this case I won't be redirecting directly from http to https on the same browser instance?

Comment: I see no reliable way your server-side code (the one that is redirecting) could open a new browser instance (and I'm not sure this would be user friendly behavior).
The core idea would be to avoid the redirection altogether if possible : either by making the page that is hosting your HTML form already in https (so that there will be no need to switch protocol), or as neonleo suggested, by making your form target action an https URL.

Answer (score 2):

I figure out there are two main questions, 
1) Basic authentication not appearing on click
 
2) hitting doGet instead of doPost

Lets create this application step by step.....
1) create 2 jsp and 1 servlet.
**index.jsp** 
`<form action="RegisterServlet"  method="post">`

`<input type="submit" name="submit">`

`</form>`

**RegisterServlet.java** 
`doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {`

`RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/welcome.jsp");`

`dispatcher.forward(request,response);`

`}`

2) apply basic authentication 
**web.xml**
`<security-constraint>`
`<web-resource-collection>`

`<web-resource-name>BasicAuth</web-resource-name>`

`<url-pattern>/RegisterServlet</url-pattern>`

`<http-method>POST</http-method>`

`<http-method>GET</http-method>`

`</web-resource-collection>`

`<auth-constraint>`

`<role-name>Admin</role-name>`

`</auth-constraint>`

`</security-constraint>`

`<login-config>`

`<auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>`

`<realm-name>Basic Authentication</realm-name>`

`</login-config>`

`<security-role>`

`<description>Admin Role</description>`

`<role-name>Admin</role-name>`

`</security-role>`

**I have provided Basic authentication for RegisterServlet. which will enable basic authentication on form submit of index.jsp. add `<http-method>GET</http-method>` as well

create role and user in **tomcat-users.xml**

`<role rolename="Admin"/>`

`<user username="Admin" password="password" roles="Admin"/>`

3) below code in web.xml
`<user-data-constraint>`

`<transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>`

`</user-data-constraint>`

 `user-data-constraint`  if making a call form http to https it will invoke GET because it is considered a bad practice, so to invoce POST, either, in action you can provide a full path(url).... or access https from a https resource.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Following your suggestions, now the BASIC Authentication is appearing correctly. But as you mentioned, it will invoke the GET. I am confused with what you meant by the `full path URL` for invoking POST. I have updated the first post with the servlet details, please let me know what will it be for my case.

Comment: Hi, There is enough explanation written in links mentioned by GPI, about why it is hitting GET instead of POST. I would suggest a work around in action instead of ``CentralController`` write ``https://localhost:8443/BasicDemo/CentralController``