# Codeigniter http -> https found 302

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, http, http-status-code-302

I'm developing a web-site with Codeigniter framework where I would want to secure my login functionality and some of my controllers. For implementing this I'm using http://sajjadhossain.com/2008/10/27/ssl-https-urls-and-codeigniter/  -method.

In some reason while form (POST) submitting I get 302 found and the request have been redirected to http GET -request. As a result I lose form parameters.

Is this a CodeIgniter issue or Apache Issue or what?

Original https POST -request:

```
> Request URL:https://localhost/xxxxx/mainpage/login
Request Method:POST
Status Code:302 Found
Request Headersview source
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:59
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cookie:__atuvc=1%7C51; ci_session=a%3A5%3A%7Bs%3A10%3A%22session_id%22%3Bs%3A32%3A%225c392f08a64b4c73e410be07b2f2162b%22%3Bs%3A10%3A%22ip_address%22%3Bs%3A9%3A%22127.0.0.1%22%3Bs%3A10%3A%22user_agent%22%3Bs%3A108%3A%22Mozilla%2F5.0+%28Windows+NT+6.1%3B+WOW64%29+AppleWebKit%2F537.36+%28KHTML%2C+like+Gecko%29+Chrome%2F31.0.1650.63+Safari%2F537.36%22%3Bs%3A13%3A%22last_activity%22%3Bi%3A1389784943%3Bs%3A9%3A%22user_data%22%3Bs%3A0%3A%22%22%3B%7Deaa32f4e7408de99c1cf025500d6ef02
Host:localhost
Origin:http://localhost
Referer:http://localhost/xxxxx/mainpage/home
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.63 Safari/537.36
Form Dataview sourceview URL encoded
username: xxxxxxxxxx
password:xxxxxxxxxx
login:Login
Response Headersview source
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Length:0
Content-Type:text/html
Date:Wed, 15 Jan 2014 11:22:29 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=100
Location:http://localhost/xxxxx/mainpage/login
Server:Apache/2.2.22 (Win64) mod_ssl/2.2.22 OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.3.13
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.3.13
```

Redirected http GET-request

```
> Request URL:http://localhost/xxxxx/mainpage/login
Request Method:GET
Status Code:302 Found
Request Headersview source
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:__atuvc=1%7C51; ci_session=a%3A5%3A%7Bs%3A10%3A%22session_id%22%3Bs%3A32%3A%225c392f08a64b4c73e410be07b2f2162b%22%3Bs%3A10%3A%22ip_address%22%3Bs%3A9%3A%22127.0.0.1%22%3Bs%3A10%3A%22user_agent%22%3Bs%3A108%3A%22Mozilla%2F5.0+%28Windows+NT+6.1%3B+WOW64%29+AppleWebKit%2F537.36+%28KHTML%2C+like+Gecko%29+Chrome%2F31.0.1650.63+Safari%2F537.36%22%3Bs%3A13%3A%22last_activity%22%3Bi%3A1389784943%3Bs%3A9%3A%22user_data%22%3Bs%3A0%3A%22%22%3B%7Deaa32f4e7408de99c1cf025500d6ef02
Host:localhost
Referer:http://localhost/xxxxx/mainpage/home
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.63 Safari/537.36
Response Headersview source
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Length:0
Content-Type:text/html
Date:Wed, 15 Jan 2014 11:22:29 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=96
Location:http://localhost/xxxxx/mainpage/home
Server:Apache/2.2.22 (Win64) mod_ssl/2.2.22 OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.3.13
Set-Cookie:ci_session=a%3A6%3A%7Bs%3A10%3A%22session_id%22%3Bs%3A32%3A%225c392f08a64b4c73e410be07b2f2162b%22%3Bs%3A10%3A%22ip_address%22%3Bs%3A9%3A%22127.0.0.1%22%3Bs%3A10%3A%22user_agent%22%3Bs%3A108%3A%22Mozilla%2F5.0+%28Windows+NT+6.1%3B+WOW64%29+AppleWebKit%2F537.36+%28KHTML%2C+like+Gecko%29+Chrome%2F31.0.1650.63+Safari%2F537.36%22%3Bs%3A13%3A%22last_activity%22%3Bi%3A1389784943%3Bs%3A9%3A%22user_data%22%3Bs%3A0%3A%22%22%3Bs%3A21%3A%22flash%3Anew%3Alogin_error%22%3Bs%3A24%3A%22Please%2C+fill+all+fields%21%22%3B%7D8b441ee2b9f1280754d04ef02292eff5; expires=Wed, 15-Jan-2014 13:22:29 GMT; path=/
X-ChromeLogger-Data:eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjoiNC4wLjAiLCJjb2x1bW5zIjpbImxvZyIsImJhY2t0cmFjZSIsInR5cGUiXSwicm93cyI6W1tbIkxvZ2luX2Z1bmN0aW9uIl0sIkM6XFx3YW1wXFx3d3dcXGVnb3RoYW1cXGFwcGxpY2F0aW9uXFxjb250cm9sbGVyc1xcbWFpbnBhZ2UucGhwIDogMTc5IiwiZXJyb3IiXSxbWyJmb3JtIHZhbGlkYXRpb24gRkFMU0UiXSwiQzpcXHdhbXBcXHd3d1xcZWdvdGhhbVxcYXBwbGljYXRpb25cXGNvbnRyb2xsZXJzXFxtYWlucGFnZS5waHAgOiAxODgiLCJ3YXJuIl1dLCJyZXF1ZXN0X3VyaSI6IlwvZWdvdGhhbVwvbWFpbnBhZ2VcL2xvZ2luIn0=
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.3.13
```

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE: .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /egotham/

    #Removes access to the system folder by users.
    #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    #previously this would not have been possible.
    #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #When your application folder isn't in the system folder
    #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
    #Submitted by: Fabdrol
    #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /egotham/index.php?/$1 [L]

    </IfModule>

    <IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
        # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
        # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
        # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

UPDATE 2:

```
function login()
{
var_dump($_POST);

$user_language = $this->session->userdata('language');
$this->lang->load('notification', $user_language);

$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required|trim|max_length[50]|xss_clean');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|trim|max_length[200]|xss_clean');

if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
{
    ChromePhp::warn('form validation FALSE');
    $this->session->set_flashdata('login_error', $this->lang->line('fill_all_fields'));
    secure_redirect('mainpage/home');
}
else
{       
    extract($_POST);   
    $remember_me = $this->input->post('remember_me');
```

Comment: Maybe `.htaccess`? (Most likely not!) Anyway post your `.htaccess` file in here. Please also see this [Q](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8138137/http-post-request-receives-a-302-should-the-redirect-request-be-a-get).

Comment: It might be your redirect method, is it using the `secure_redirect` method from http://sajjadhossain.com/2008/10/27/ssl-https-urls-and-codeigniter/?

Comment: The particular problem happens before secure_redirect have been reached. I loose form parameters while https-post transfers to http-get -> secure_redirect will newer fired. But yes - same problem (302 found / https -> http) occurs also with secure_redirect too..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the method you mentioned, but the way I have got it to work in a previous project is to set a second base url in the config (like "base_url_secure"), and then set the form post to the secure version directly, which means you won't need a redirect.

I don't think you can redirect with post, so the form should post directly to the secure url.

Comment: Sorry my bad english - "redirect" seems to be little bit dangerous word in this context. I think I did quite much same as you described above. I have base_url and secure_base_url and I'm using it like:  echo form_open(secure_base_url() . 'mainpage/login');

Comment: Unfortunately no. HTTP/1.1 302 Found -message occur when submitting the form and it automatically redirects the query to http get request..

Comment: Can you show the code from the function that the form is posting to? Can you var_dump and exit as the first line of that function and see the post vars?

Comment: In login() -> var_dump($_POST); -> array (size=0) empty -  Is it possible problem cause that I have unsecure (http) page, where I call this form_open(secure_base_url() . 'mainpage/login'); ?

Comment: Are you still being redirected? Try using your browsers debugging tools to see http requests, and enable persistence. That way you can see if the content is posting before the redirect happens.