# Suppressing 302 Error returned by httr POST

Tags: json, r, curl, httr

I'm using the R httr POST function to send a body of jSON to an API.  The API is, properly, returning a 302: Found message, but httr is exiting the function before I'm able to grab the body of response (which is a jSON body, with some key bits of info.)

Running httr with the Verbose() argument, the following is the response:

```
<- HTTP/1.1 302 Found
<- Cache-Control: no-cache
<- Pragma: no-cache
<- Content-Length: 47
<- Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
<- Expires: -1
Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
  necessary data rewind wasn't possible
```

I've run the same cURL post from terminal, and can confirm what I'm sending produces a reply from the API with both the 302 and the desired body.

For reference my R code follows.  (note: y is the jSON formatted body)

```
POST("https://thewebsite",authenticate("myusername","mypassword",type="basic"),
    add_headers("Content-Type" = "application/json"),
    body = y, verbose())
```

Any thoughts on how to bypass the error and capture the 302 message content?

Comment: Curious...what happens if you `PUT` instead of `POST`?  Not meant as a solution - just for troubleshooting.

Comment: Gave PUT a try and it appears it's not an option with this particular API.  Produces a "405:Method Not Allowed" error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just spent some time battling with this issue myself. The problem comes down to a difference in the HTTP spec (which is basically what RCurl adheres to) and what browsers actually do.

The sequence of events is this:

1. You issue POST request to server
2. Server handles request and issues you a redirect to a new url
3. RCurl treats this like new request like a POST, and tries to replay the body. (Browser don't try and resend the data)
4. It can't resend the data because the underlying RCurl isn't constructed in such a way this is possible (that's why curl complains: "necessary data rewind wasn't possible")

The solution is simple - disable the following of redirects with `config(followlocation = 0L)`:

```
POST("https://thewebsite",
  authenticate("myusername","mypassword"),
  content_type_json(),
  config(followlocation = 0L),
  body = y, 
)

# PS with httr 0.4 you can simplify to
POST("https://thewebsite",
  authenticate("myusername","mypassword"),
  config(followlocation = 0L),
  body = x, encode = "json" 
)
```

You'll then need to look at the contents of the location field, and do the redirect yourself.

For more discussion of the underlying issue, see:

- [HTTP: POST request receives a 302, should the redirect-request be a GET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8138137)
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/99894

Comment: It's possible that `config(post = TRUE)` might also fix the problem, while handling requests, but I can't confirm without a reproducible example

Comment: @TS4 does using `post = TRUE` instead of `followlocation = 0L` fix the problem?

Comment: Oh sorry, looks like we posted at the same time.  followlocation = 0L fixed the issue.  Let me test the config(post = TRUE) now.

Comment: (Post = TRUE) did not resolve the issue, it errors out before I'm able to grab the body of the 302 message.  The followlocation =0L did the trick, thanks again for that.

Comment: @TS4 can you please try the dev version of httr? `devtools::install_github("hadley/httr")`. I think I've fixed the problem there (i.e. you shouldn't need any extra config commands)

Comment: That works.  Installed the dev version, commented out the `(followinglocation= 0L)`, and was able to extract the 302 message body.

Comment: Awesome. Glad I finally got to the bottom of this - thanks for the help!