# webRequest API redirect uses http method of parent request

Tags: firefox, redirect, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions, chrome-webrequest

I'm using the [webRequest-API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest) in a WebExtension to monitor requests made by the client. This works quite well, however the API doesn't behave as expected in case of a redirect:

In this case a `POST` is issued which is answered with a `302 FOUND` and a new location. My browser (Firefox 57, other versions and other browsers - e.g. Chrome - act the same way) follows this redirect and now issues a `GET` to the new location.

[image]

Unfortunately the webRequest-API behaves differently: It traces the first `POST` (which is correct) but than handles the second request as a `POST`, too, whereas it should be a `GET`. This is a severe problem since the API traces something my browser supposedly did, which it actually did in another way...

This scenario (the browser-part) can be reproduced by following [this link to surfnet.nl](https://crowd.surfnet.nl/Shibboleth.sso/Login?target=https%3A%2F%2Fcrowd.surfnet.nl%2Fcrowd%2Fplugins%2Fservlet%2Fssocookie%3FredirectTo%3Dhttps%3A%2F%2Fwiki.surfnet.nl%2Fdashboard.action%26originalHost%3Dhttps%3A%2F%2Fwiki.surfnet.nl&entityID=https://engine.surfconext.nl/authentication/idp/metadata&os_destination=%2F) and choosing an IDP form the list (e.g. Academisch Medisch Centrum).

**So, long story short: Why does the webRequest-API behave different form the way browsers behave?** And is there a way to let it exactly trace the browser's actions?

Interestingly the webRequest-API might do it correctly, [regarding the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/302):

> Even if **the specification requires the method, and the body, not to be altered** when the redirection is performed, **not all user-agents conform here** [*browsers obviously change the method!*], and you can still find buggy software out there. It is therefore recommended to set the 302 code only as a response for GET or HEAD methods and to use 307 Temporary Redirect instead, as the method change is explicitly prohibited in that case.
>   In the cases where you want the method used to be changed to GET, use 303 See Other instead.

---

**EDIT:**
It seems as if browser change the method on a `302` due to historical reasons, even tho it contradicts [RFC 2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.3)...

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/8139246/594832
- https://trac.ietf.org/trac/httpbis/ticket/160
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/8138447/594832

Anyways... the question remains: how can I induce the webRequest-API to act the same way?

Comment: Please open a bug at https://bugzilla.mozilla.org

Comment: @Smile4ever thank you for your comment, but I don't think it's actually a bug.

Comment: If you want an answer to your question, that's probably the best place to ask even if you think it's not really a bug.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested, I ended up with the following:

The docs let me to [this](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#type-BlockingResponse) (`redirectUrl`):

> [...] Redirects initiated by a redirect action use the original request method for the redirect, with one exception: If the redirect is initiated at the onHeadersReceived stage, then the redirect will be issued using the GET method. [...]

Although the statement above gave me some hope, the `method` of that redirected request was still labeled as a POST...

So I updated the code to something roughly like this:

```
// Keep track of all requests issued so far and their responses
var httpRequests = [];

// Redirected requests come in with their originating parents' ID
browser.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(request => {
    // Check if the request is a redirect
    var isRedirected = function(requestId) {
        var parentRequest = httpRequests.find(r => r.req.requestId === requestId);
        if (parentRequest != null && parentRequest.res != null && parentRequest.res.statusCode === 302) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    };

    // The webRequest-API seems to keep the HTTP verbs which is correct in resepct to RFC 2616 but
    // differs from a typical browser behaviour which will usually change the POST to a GET. So do we here...
    if (request.method === 'POST' && isRedirected(request.requestId)) {
        console.log(`Redirected 302-request '${request.requestId}' is a POST but is here changed to a GET to conform to browser behaviour...`);
        request.method = 'GET';
    }

    // Store the request
    var entry = {
        id: id,
        req: request
    };
    httpRequests.push(entry);
});

browser.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(response => {
    // Store the response alongside the request
    var entry = httpRequests.find(req => req.id === response.requestId);
    entry.res = response;

    // If it turns out that a request should be redirected...
    if (response.statusCode === 302) {
        var location = response.responseHeaders.find(header => header.name.toLowerCase() === "location");
        console.log(`Redirecting request '${id}' to new location '${location.value}'...`);

        // The new location is set as redirectUrl, which results in a new invocation of onBeforeRequest with
        // the current requestId
        return {
            redirectUrl: location.value
        };
    }
});
```

What happens?

1. Say `onBeforeRequest` receives a new request `2640` which is a POST.
2. `onHeadersReceived` gets the response which says that this request should be redirected to a new location (`302`).
3. The code above does so by setting the `redirectUrl` to that new location.
4. Then `onBeforeRequest` is triggered again. The webRequest-API passes the same requestId to it (`2640`).
5. The code checks if there's a parent for this request, and in this case it's true.
6. The method (which is still POST) is then modified to GET.

For the request lifecycle have a look at the illustration [in the docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#life_cycle).